# SAS Display Manager: Viewtable commands

Tags: sas, display-manager

SAS DM offers some handy tools for viewing data accessible via the command console. For example "vt library.table" will display the table you would like to view in table viewer. or " 'columns' colname" will only display the variable COLNAME. However this function does not seem to be able to take more than 1 argument. For example " 'columns' a b" will not display columns A and B. My questions are:

Does anyone know how to include multiple variables into this statement?

Also, is there a way to use something equivalent to a LIKE operator in this command prompt, or maybe even use a regular expression? For example, find all variable beginning with "XYZ".

Lastly, is there a DM command to view table properties?

If anyone knows the answers to these questions, your help would be much appreciated as there seems to be very little information about SAS DM out there.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about a like operator or the properties tab, but to show multiple variables you can do:

```
dm "vt sashelp.class; columns ""sex age""";
```

You can bring up the vars tab like so, and then click on the properties tab:

```
dm "vars sashelp.class";
```

You might find this page helpful:
[SAS Display Manager commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233056/sas-display-manager-commands)

Comment: awesome! VARS is exactly what I was looking for when I was talking about table properties. As for selecting multiple columns, it looks like I was doing it wrong -- I was enclosing 'columns' in quotes, but not the actual variable names. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it. I'll leave the question open for a little longer, just in case anyone knows how to use a LIKE operator or equivalent in DM.