# Is there a shortcut to run current code block, without selecting?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Many other IDEs have a feature to run the code block your cursor is placed in. According to the [docs](https://documentation.sas.com/?activeCdc=egdoccdc&cdcId=egcdc&cdcVersion=8.3&docsetId=ega11y&docsetTarget=ega11y.htm&locale=en#n1trj0zraqsv83n17jwpj3h2ztzx), SAS EG has the following shortcut:

`Run the selected code -> F3`

But is there a shortcut for the following?

`Run code block your cursor is placed in -> X`

It's tedious to have to constantly reach for the mouse to click-drag-select, then hit F3.

Preemptive thank you from the laziest lizard on earth.

Comment: Does `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `←` helps?

Comment: It is helpful as a cursor highlighting shortcut, along with shift-up/shift-down. Thank you for your suggestion @whymath!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no shortcut (or way to create such a shortcut).  SAS requires you to highlight it.

However, there are some options to make this easier.  You can see the [SAS EG documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?softwareId=eguide&softwareVersion=8.3&softwareContextId=KeyboardShortcuts&locale=en-US&requestor=inapp) for some keyboard shortcuts; one option, for example, is to use code folding (Alt + numeric keypad hyphen) to collapse the current data step/proc step/macro, and then you can easily highlight that one line (with shift-end, as it places your cursor at the start of the line).

Also see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857193/sas-enhanced-editor-submitting-code-block-without-manually-highlighting?rq=1) about SAS Enhanced Editor, which has the same basic solution, plus some other ideas.

Comment: That's a perfect thread you linked. Thank you!

Comment: Just to emphasize, you can't use the hyphen on the lefthand side of backspace. You need to use it on your *numpad*.