# In Base SAS, how can I auto refresh the explorer?

Tags: automation, sas

I'm fairly sure this must be something that has bugged others and so there must be a solution.  I write my code and want to quickly check the dataset, but it isn't there.  I need to select the window, click View and click refresh.  Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use or a macro I can write that does this for me?

I know this is lazy but it bugs me.
Any thoughts are appreciated.
J

Comment: As a side note, this is probably the #2 reason I like using enterprise guide as a programmer: the ease of viewing datasets you just ran.

Comment: It's why I prefer using R, but apparently a multibillion euro company doesn't want to do exactly what I want :).  I have Enterprise guide but with a different setup. The team all use base, and we use rsubmit which would mean our code being potentially incompatible...

Comment: Hmm, EG should work with rsubmit just fine (via localserver)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this programmatically using:

```
dm "next explorer; refresh";
```

Or assign it to a shortcut key (eg F2) as follows:

```
dm "keydef F2 'next explorer; refresh'";
```

If you just want to open the last dataset, you could also assign this to a shortcut key:

```
dm "keydef F3 'vt &syslast'";
```

If the dataset is in a remote location, the following could be adapted for your needs (note the embedded sas code which gets submitted):

```
dm 'keydef F4 "submit ''rsubmit; %nrstr(%sysrput lastDS=&syslast;) endrsubmit;''; vt rwork.%scan(&lastDS,2,.)"';
```

More shortcuts available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233056/sas-display-manager-commands)!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed examples.

Comment: Always forget I can't enter in comments.  For the explorer it seems I need to click into the explorer to make this happen, its still quicker but I'm wondering if I can do it without that.  Also on the last data set, that's also cool but as I'm using rsubmit, it opens the last work file not rwork.  How would I adapt your code to get that?  Really appreciate these secrets

Comment: Try:   `dm 'keydef F4 "submit ''rsubmit; %nrstr(%sysrput lastDS=&syslast;) endrsubmit;''; vt rwork.%scan(&lastDS,2,.)"'; `

Comment: hmm - works for me.  If you can ask a new question with this particular issue (screenshots would help) happy to take a look!

Comment: Thanks @RawFocus - I've created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153344/sas-how-to-open-most-recent-file-when-using-remote-connection)