# Keys shortcut to focus on 'results viewer'

Tags: sas

**What is the keys-codeword for focusing on the results viewer?**

I can focus on the program editor using the keys-kodeword `wpgm`.

In the picture below I have programmed F4 to focus and resize the program editor.
[image]

**How can I do the same thing for the 'results viewer'?**

**PS**

And where can i find a list of all available 'keys-codewords'?
**PS**

I am using SAS Base v. 9.4

By 'results viewer' I am refering to this window:
[image]

Comment: Check out this thread for finding DMS commands.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233056/sas-display-manager-commands

Comment: `odsresults` is the results tab - but I'm not sure there is a keyword for the viewer.  If it exists, it's likely accessible by `next [whateveritscalled]`, similar to how `next` works with  `viewtable`s.